# ZF2 Developer Tools with AngularJs

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework2

I have installed ZF2 Developer Tools module and for normal pages it worlks as it should.

But my admin section is AngularJs based and there is no page refresh to get the toolbars details. So how can i still get the developer tools information like request time, memory usage and query profiler report when using AngularJs and ajax request ?